# Float overflowed but not when a printf argument in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, arguments, overflow, printf

Why is it that when my overflow calculation is an argument of the printf() function,the float does not overflow, but when the coded calculation is assigned to a separate variable ,float_overflowed, and is not an argument of the printf function I get the expected result of 'inf'? 
Why does this happen? What is causing this difference?

The code and results that led me to this question are below.

Here is my code that didn't execute as expected when the calculation is an argument:

```
float float_overflow;
float_overflow=3.4e38;
printf("This demonstrates floating data type overflow. We should  get an \'inf\' value.\n%e*10=%e.\n\n",float_overflow, float_overflow*10);     //No overflow?
```

The result:

```
This demonstrates floating data type overflow. We should  get an 'inf' value.
3.400000e+38*10=3.400000e+39.
```

And, when the calculation is not an argument:

```
float float_upperlimit;
float float_overflowed;
float_upperlimit=3.4e38;
float_overflowed=float_upperlimit*10;
printf("This demonstrates floating data type overflow. We should  get an \'inf\' value.\n%e*10=%e.\n\n",float_upperlimit, float_overflowed);        //for float overflow
```

and its result:

```
This demonstrates floating data type overflow. We should  get an 'inf' value.
3.400000e+38*10=inf.
```

Comment: From my understanding, the "overflow" opccurs when storing the information in a variable. Because, otherwise, it's just another bit in the exponent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the compiler is not constrained to do the arithmetic in `float` but it might well use double. 5.2.4.2.1 of the current C standard has:

> Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and
>   precision), the values yielded by operators with floating operands and
>   values subject to the usual arithmetic conversions and of floating
>   constants are evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be
>   greater than required by the type. The use of evaluation formats is
>   characterized by the implementation-defined value of FLT_EVAL_METHOD

So you only know to force the value to be `float` when you assign it. Since in the context of the `printf` call (it is a va_arg function) any such argument is needed as `double` anyhow, there is no conversion taking place in case that `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is of value `1`, that is all `float` arithmetic is done in `double`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Can I change the FLT_EVAL_METHOD? If so, how?

Comment: @JonPlotner, no, not in a portable way. The value of that constant is chosen by the compiler implementor. I guess allowing changes would be quite difficult, because this could lead to inconsistency with the `math.h` functions.

Comment: @JonPlotner If you are using GCC, then using the command-line options `-mfpmath=sse -msse2` should configure GCC in a way such that it defines FLT_EVAL_METHOD as 0.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that for the `"%e"` format (and all other floating-point formating codes), the argument is actually a `double`. See e.g. the table [in this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

That means that when you do the calculation "in-line" as the argument you do now actually overflow. But when you do it for the variable, then it's indeed overflowed and that will carry when used in the `printf` call.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly I believe you are saying when calculated in-line "float_overflow*10" has not been declared as a float, but is stored as a double in the computers memory because the specifier "%e" point/makes space for a double, and not the smaller float? I just want to make sure I understand. I once was lost, but now I am found. Thank you Sheppard of programmers :)

Comment: This answer contains only half of the story. The type of the multiplication `float_overflow*10` is `float` before it is promoted to `double`. With FLT_EVAL_METHOD=0, `printf("%e", float_overflow*10)` **does** printf `inf`. Jens Gustedt's answer contains the second half of the explanation.

Comment: “for the `%e` format […] the argument is actually a `double`” is also misleading. The promotion to `double` does not occur because `%e` expects it but because of the “The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.” part of C99's 6.5.2.2:7. If the format had been `%Le` the argument would “actually” have been a `long double` but that would not have meant that the expression would have automatically been promoted to `long double`.

Comment: Thank you for the further clarification. What is a default argument promotion?